# PHP upload png error

Tags: php, image

I have a form that upload images to the server. In the PHP code I read the image extension and use the function `imagepng` or `imagejpeg`.
The problem appear when the image extension don't correspond to the real image type.

For example, if I have a **jpeg image** and the user changes the extension to `png`, the function try to use `imagepng` and return an error.

There is a way to read the true type of the image before upload it?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to post some code here, otherwhise we can't give you the right answers. :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php might help you

Comment: In the end I used a succession of try catch with the fucntions that allows to upload the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`exif-imagetype`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) accomplishes what you're looking for. It determines the image format by reading the file instead of relying solely on the extension. It takes the filename as a parameter and returns a number corresponding to the detected image type. In your case specifically, you're going to want to watch for a return value of 2 for `.jpg`, or 3 for `.png`.